# Restricting thread count and Java concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I couldn't find an example of this specific case using the latest JAVA concurrent routines.

I plan to use `threads` to process items from an open queue which may contain 0 to thousands requests.   I want to restrict so at at any given time there be no less than 0 and no more than say 10 threads handling queue items.

Is there a Java concurrent process geared towards this specific type of case?

Comment: check out the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. if there's not one that will work for you right out of the box, then you could always wrap it...

Comment: "there be no less than 0", do you mean you don't want a negative number of thread? ;)

Answer (score 10):

I think a thread pool is what you are looking for. Take a look at ExecutorService and Executors.

ExecutorService : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Executors : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Getting a new Thread fixed thread-pool that processes max. 10 Thread at once :

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

With the submit Method you pass Callables or Runnables to the Pool.

For your use case you need a process that looks into the Queue, if there is a new request a Callable or Runnable has to be created and passed to the thread-pool. The pool ensures that max. 10 threads are executed at once.

This is a very small tutorial : http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/essential/threads/group.html

A nice thing working with thread-pools is that the submit method returns a Future object, which supports return types for the executed threads.

Future : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

I hope this helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: +1 The fixed thread pool also has a queue so you don't need to add one.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't think that way, just thought the queue of requests still exists.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same task: 
I used the `BlockingQueue` of the `java.util.concurrent` package. I created X worker threads which reads one action from the queue, processes it, and when ready take the next. This is simple, and it works fine.

If you use X = 10 Worker threads, then your task is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a thread pool executor with corePoolSize=0 and maximumPoolSize=10.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually have access to the creation of the threads, and you only manage the queue access, a solution could simply be to use a `Semaphore` object (see the [docs page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)).

The idea is for a global semaphore, accessed in the same way the queue is accessed, to be initialized to the number `max_threads` (say, 10).

Before accessing the queue for item processing, a thread would first [acquire](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire%28%29) a permit from the semaphore, which would block if a `max_threads` number of threads had already started processing items from the queue.

After an item is processed by some thread, that thread should finally [release](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release%28%29) the permit, thus allowing more threads to process other items.

Note that the acquiring/releasing of a permit should be done using a try-finally block, so that even if some exception is thrown from the item processing, the semaphore remains in a consistent state. The code should look like this:

```
semaphore.acquire().
try {
    // retrieve item from queue and process it
}
finally {
    semaphore.release();
}
```